# Disabling Mouse events - Pygame

Tags: python, input, pygame

I have a game made that, when you die, a message appears reading "game over. Press any key to play again."

However, this counts mouse input as I have no if statements in my for loop. I was wondering if there was a certain key word I can use? I can't seem to find one on google.

```
if event.type != MOUSEMOVE:
```

This is what I am hoping for but maybe there is another way to do it. Thanks for any help!

Comment: I'm not too familiar with pygame, but it does seem to have an event type for mouse movement: `pygame.MOUSEMOTION`. Have you tried this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Do this before the event loop:

```
pygame.event.set_blocked(pygame.MOUSEMOTION)
```

You'll probably want to block some other events, too. See more here:
https://www.pygame.org/docs/ref/event.html